# How come when I render my animation, the audio is clipped when I stitch together the pieces?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, video-sequence-editor, audio

I have a slow computer, and I have an animation of 4400 frames. If I render all at once, it would crash. So I made this Python script to try to help me:

```
#START OF SCRIPT

import bpy
import time

wait = time.sleep
start = 0
end = 4400
increment = 10

current = start

for i in range(start,end + increment,increment):

    wait(2)

    current = i

    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_start = current + 1
    bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_end = current + increment
    bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)
#END OF SCRIPT
```

And I get all of the pieces of the animation:

[image: Animation Pieces]

But when I try to stitch it together like so:

[image: Stitch]

It just doesn't line up. The audio and video are clipped in-between, and the amount of audio frames just doesn't line up with the video.

Did I do something wrong with the script? The stitching? The animation? Please help soon, as I am trying to make this as a Christmas present.

These are the steps I took: https://www.youtube.com/embed/VVY6C2K_1wM
Here is the file: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33331

Comment: If you post links for the first two video clips and also the first two audio clips then people will have something to test with.  You might also want to update your answer with: Step1, Step2, Step3, etc... without skipping anything that you are doing.

Comment: @MarcClintDion I added a link to a video.

Comment: your explanation was fine without the video.  The problem is that without some of the assets that are causing the problem, a person who wants to look at this issue has to recreate all the assets by guessing at your setup.  This could take all day(or more) and the results will likely not help you because the person was only guessing at where your problem may be.

Comment: I added the file.

Comment: Don't render out movie strips. Render out images in PNG and add the images as an image strip. Then add the original audio clip afterwards, in the final edit.

Comment: I unfortunately can't test for you, but I think rendering one image at a time should be easier on your computer than what you're doing now.

Comment: @NaioaiStudios So can I add this ( bpy.ops.sound.mixdown() ) line to the script, change to PNG, and then render?

Comment: Don't use the script =) Change output to PNG and let Blender render out all the images for you. Test with 100 frames(images) first. When that's done, you go to video editing and press "Add" -> "Image" and select all 100 images. Blender will then treat this as a movie strip.

Comment: Then you add the audio clip, and adjust so the timing matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to not render out movie strips to a single move file. Instead you should render images as .PNG files and add the images together in the video sequence editor. Then add the original audio clip afterwards, in the final edit. I wouldn't recommend using a script at all.

Change output to PNG:

[image]

Set range to 100 frames(to test with):

[image]

Then press the normal animation-render button:

[image]

When that's done, you go to video editing and press "Add" -> "Image" and select all 100 images.

[image]

Blender will then treat this as a movie strip.

Then you add the audio clip, and adjust so the timing matches

Comment: It worked. Instead of editing the sound manually, I just did a mixdown for the audio (flac file with all the audio).